# Django 1.8 Run a specific migration

Tags: django, migration, django-migrations

In django 1.8 is there a way to run a specific migration and that migration only.

Not for one app only but a specific file in that apps migrations directory.

EDIT TO ORIGINAL:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/aku/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/aku/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/aku/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/aku/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/aku/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 146, in handle
    plan = executor.migration_plan(targets)
  File "/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/aku/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 50, in migration_plan
    self.loader.graph.node_map[target].children
KeyError: ('wagtailcore', '0001_initial')
```

Did a little searching and located this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24225#no1

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You can tell Django to move to a specific migration

```
./manage.py migrate myapp 0005_migration_to_run
```

But Django will run **every** migration up to (or back to) the migration you've chosen.

You could try [faking](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake) to the migration before

```
./manage.py migrate --fake myapp 0004_previous_migration
./manage.py migrate myapp 0005_migration_to_run
```

You might then want to fake to the migration you started at.

Comment: I was trying this and it didn't work.When I gave the full name, it couldn't find the file.However, this format worked

**./manage.py migrate myapp 0005**


[Django documentation Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations)