# In Django , Is it possible to migrate any perticular specific file?

Tags: python, django, database, migrate

Currently I am learning django and learning migration related stuff.

I have found that we can migrate specific app using `python manage.py migrate app-name` but not found how to migrate specific migration file named `python manage.py migrate 0024_auto_20200827_0706.py`.

If I will do `python manage.py migrate 0024_auto_20200827_0706.py`, it will revert migration from this point or file but not doing migrate for this specific file.

My question : is it possible to do migrate for specific file if yes then How is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django 1.8 Run a specific migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531350/django-1-8-run-a-specific-migration)

Comment: What is your use-case for this? Typically running a single migration out of a stack will bring your code and database into an inconsistent state. (If it works at all.)

Comment: Actually I do not have use-case but just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Karthik  If I will do --fake for previous migrations like 0022,0023 so what about next migrations like starting with 0025,0026 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to directly run a single migration out of sequence.

If the migration is a data migration of some sort that could otherwise be run out of sequence (i.e. it doesn't depend on schema changes, or is dangerous to run), I would recommend refactoring it into

- a "migration utility" function in e.g. `myapp/migration_utils`
- the migration itself that just calls the above function
- a management command that calls the above function

Then you can call the management command manually should you need to, but the migration would be run in-sequence otherwise.

Comment: I am not able to understand it properly. It would be great if you can explain me in detail.